# Call several endpoints in an Oraclize nested query and return an array

Tags: solidity, contract-development, oracles

I am trying to get an average of ETH/USD conversion rate through Oraclize. My query works well when calling one single HTTP endpoint but I would like to call several endpoints within the same query and have the results returned in an array so that I can get average and remove outliers.

Currently, the best I managed to get is a response through computing the result of two queries nested in a Wolfram alpha query: 
[WolframAlpha] (${[URL] ...} + ${[URL] ...}) / 2

But this is not very satisfying and I would like to have an array of values that I can process in solidity. I suppose nesting/computation would also be possible but seems like a hassle.

I am trying to find the exact syntax for the following "query":

[${[URL]...}, ${[URL]...}, ${[URL]...} ...].

What would be the syntax if this is possible? If not, what solution would you suggest?